# When I enter a date it will only insert the sample date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I have tried entering the date by right click "insert date" and choosing `mm/dd/yy`

when I hit enter the date appears as the sample date and I can't get the current date to appear.

Comment: Where are you right clicking "insert date"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a cell that uses the date of the current day, meaning it will be different tomorrow than it is today, you want to enter `=TODAY()` in the cell.

If formatting the date is what you're looking to do, see the picture below. You can also add a custom date format by selecting the bottom option of the drop-down box and use syntax like `DD/MMMM_YYYY` which would output like `14/April_2016`, likewise `MM/DD/YY` for `04/14/16`

[image]

Via the comments- Entering a date without some sort of dividing punctuation between the numbers will result in likely unexpected behavior. For example, entering `041416`, you may expect to see "April 14th, 2016" in whichever form selected. However the way Excel handles input like this is that it will count that number of days beyond January 1st, 1900. This is why you will actually get the date `5/22/2013` by entering `041416`.

To learn more about this, follow this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I have been doing this but I continue to get the date below: I am entering 041416

05/22/13

05/22/13

05/22/13

Comment: Excel reads input like `041416` differently than you may think. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US for more info, specifically the `Remarks` section

Comment: @Janie As jatuttle0 indicates, 5/22/2013 is 41,416 days from Jan 1, 1900.  So that is why you see what you see.

Comment: @Janie Welcome to Super User! You should [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1065411/edit) your question to include the information from your comment here. Including an example is a good way to make sure your question is clear.